# JQM: Back button in header won't go away

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

Strangely the code below produces an unwanted back button in the header. As far as I know the default behaviour of the latest JQM is a disabled back button. Even trying to force it off, it still appears in the left control group. I've placed the buttons inside
control groups as I want multiple buttons inside the header.

**Update:** Tried having the right button outside the control group - no difference.

**Update II:** Swapping out fieldset with controlgroup makes no difference.

[image: Back button]

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline" data-add-back-btn="false">

<div data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-btn-left">  

<a href="all-devices-list.html" data-ajax="true" data-role="button" data-icon="home_button_header" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
<a href="phone-device.html" data-ajax="true" data-role="button" data-icon="phone_button_header" data-iconpos="notext">Phone</a>

</div>                                  

<h2><a href="#"><img src="themes/images/header.png" alt="Header" title="Header"></a></h2>

<div data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-btn-right">

<a href="add-device.html" data-role="button" data-icon="plus_icon_header" data-iconpos="notext">Plus</a>

</div>                                  

</div>
```